# Java audio not playing when exporting to JAR

Tags: java, audio, jar, embedded-resource

I'm playing a background music and in Eclipse it works fine.

The file is located in src/audio.mp3

This is how I reference it:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("audio.mp3").toURI());
```

When I export it to a Jar file and execute it, there is no music. What am I doing wrong?

I am using JavaZOOM Advanced Player.

Comment: Try getResource("/audio.mp3").
Extract your jar file and check directory tree.

Comment: @MokarromHossain I tried adding that slash and it's not working yet. I checked the directory tree and all the files are in the main directory beside all the .class and  .png files.

Comment: When running from jar, names are case-sensitive, e.g., audio.mp3 and Audio.mp3 are different.

Comment: @MokarromHossain file names are lower case.

Comment: Does getClass().getResource("audio.mp3") return null?

Comment: @MokarromHossain SOLVED IT! Instead of using getResource I used directly getResourceAsStream.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* In that instance, treating an embedded resource as if it was a `File` object. That just won't work for a resource embedded in a Jar file. Get the URL of (or the stream to) the resource and work with that instead.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy you should post working code as an answer, so others could see it